# slowcheetah.transformtask task failed unexpectedly.system.unauthorizedaccessexception

Tags: visual-studio-2017, slowcheetah

Getting following error when using custom json configuration file.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "SlowCheetah.TransformTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\Data\…\Settings.Release.json' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Jdt.JsonTransformation..ctor(String transformFile, IJsonTransformationLogger logger)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.JsonTransformer.Transform(String sourcePath, String transformPath, String destinationPath)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.TransformTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() OzCruisingHangfireAgent.Program

Best Regards,
Damodar

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue.

The JSON transformer in SlowCheetah v3.1.66 doesn't support the source or transform files being read-only yet.

See the following issues:
https://github.com/Microsoft/slow-cheetah/issues/86
https://github.com/Microsoft/json-document-transforms/issues/16

The merged [PR#17](https://github.com/Microsoft/json-document-transforms/pull/17) has a fix for [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Jdt](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Jdt/), but it hasn't been released yet.

Here are a few work arounds:

1. Make all files writeable when checking out of source control.
2. Call the [Attrib MSBuild task](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Documentation/TaskDocs.md#Attrib) before the transformation to remove the read-only file attribute.

For example:

`<Attrib Files="D:\Data\…\Settings.Release.json" Normal="true"/>`

3. Call the [Exec MSBuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task?view=vs-2017) before the transformation to remove the read-only file attribute.

For example:

`<Exec Command="attrib -R &quot;D:\Data\…\Settings.Release.json&quot;"/>`

Comment: Hi Rami A., Thanks but it didn't work.
Won't be able to do 1. 
If I do that it's working fine, don't want to check out file when building a project. I did following 
Attrib Files="$(ProjectDir)Settings.json" Normal="true" ReadOnly="false"
Attrib Files="$(ProjectDir)Settings.Debug.json" Normal="true" ReadOnly="false"
Exec Command=attrib -R "$(ProjectDir)Settings.json"
Exec Command=attrib -R "$(ProjectDir)Settings.Debug.json"  
Would you be able to check the syntax?

Comment: The syntax looks fine. You can do either 2 or 3; you don't have to do both because they do the same thing.

Comment: Hi Rami.A, No luck. Tried them both separately. - Damodar

Comment: @damodar, what output do you get?

Comment: Hi Rami, this is what I get  The command "<Exec Command="attrib -R D:\Data\...\Settings.Debug.json" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" />" exited with code 255

Comment: @damodar, you need to set more verbosity in the MSBuild build output in `Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run` and then check the Output window for the detailed error message.

Comment: the build log says The syntax of the command is incorrect.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1332,5): error MSB3073: The command "<Attrib Files="D:\Data\...\Settings.json" Normal="true" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" />" exited with code 255.
2>Done executing task "Exec" -- FAILED. Used <Attrib Files="$(ProjectDir)Settings.json" Normal="true"/> tried Settings.Debug.json as well

Comment: Try removing the `xmlns` attribute on the `Attrib` task. It's not required.

Comment: Also, if your file contains spaces, you'll have to surround the path in quotes like the example using the `Exec` command.

Comment: Does it work inside Visual Studio? You can try to increase the verbosity of the MSBuild log output in `Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run` and then check the log for more details about the error.

Comment: Hi Rami A, <Attrib Files="$(ProjectDir)Settings.json" Normal="true"/> I basically have this in Pre-Build event command line: in the project property. The folder name is long there spaces in the folder structure.

Comment: A, here's the detailed error:  2>Done executing task "Exec" -- FAILED. (TaskId:22)
2>Done building target "PreBuildEvent" in project "Program.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:28)
2>Target "_CheckForCompileOutputs: (TargetId:29)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "D:\Data\..\Program.csproj" (target "_CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites" depends on it):

Comment: Which verbosity levels did you set?

Comment: Have selected "Diagnostic"

Comment: Can you share your project?